# Subtract a specific number of white spaces / characters from a string

Tags: python

```
string = "    Hello!"

print(string)
```

**Output:**`”    Hello!”`

This code below works for adding 4 white spaces to the string:

```
space= " "

print(space*4 + string)
```

**Output:**`”        Hello!”`

This code below works to get the original output:

```
print(-1*space*4 + string)
```

**Output:**`”    Hello!”`

But the code below do not subtract 4 additional white spaces

```
print((-2)*space*4 + string)
```

**Output:**`”    Hello!”`

I'm wondering how i can accomplish this output below with "*string*" and "*space*":

**Output:**”Hello!”

Or at least how I can subtract a specific number of white spaces / characters from a string.

Any ideas?

Comment: new_str = old_str[5:]

Comment: Both print(-1*space*4 + string)  and print((-2)*space*4 + string) does not work. Original string is intact after this step print(space*4 + string). You are not modifying the original string at all. Modify original string as 'string = space*4 + string' then both -1 and -2 print won't work.

When you multiply any character/white space with -1 or other negative number then the resulting string is an empty string.

Comment: @Sunnysinh Solanki  Oh okay. Well that explains the logic behind it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey you can use it like this
`print(str[4:])`

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to remove all white spaces you can use method .strip() and .rstrip() - reverse strip.

```
>>> string="    Hello!"
>>> string
'    Hello!'
>>> string.strip()
'Hello!'
>>>
```

another example:

```
>>> string.replace(' ','')
'Hello!'
>>>
```

or you can use regexp, but it is a complex solution for this task.
about your question.

```
>>> print(-1*space*4 + string)
    Hello!
>>> print((-2)*space*4 + string)
    Hello!
>>>
```

The function print will not strip whitespaces. In both cases the code 
`-1*space*4` and `(-2)*space*4` don't work.
For getting string without spaces at all you can use `strip` as I mentioned above or use exact value what you want to print, like `print(string[4:])`

Answer (score 0):

Use n variable to store no white spaces that to be removed from a string,
   please check the below code:

```
s="    Hello!"
n=4
new_str = s[n:]
print(new_str)
```